# Why this adds node_modules in host machine CMD [ -d "node_modules" ] && npm run dev || npm install && npm run dev but CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"] dont?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, node-modules

I've been studying dockerfiles right now and when I thought I understand it, later I found out I don't!

I'm trying to build a next js app with a persistent node_modules in my machine. At first, here is my dockerfile

```
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

And here is a snippet of my docker-compose.yml

```
    # first volume but still empty node_modules (But inside container, it is present)
    volumes:
      - ./../../.:/app
    # second volume code but still empty node_modules (But inside container, it is present)
    volumes:
      - ./../../.:/app
      - /app/node_modules
```

Above set up is only creating an empty node_modules on host but inside the container, node modules is not empty. Then I have seen a code somewhere and it works, but I couldn't understand it why.

```
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json .

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ -d "node_modules" ] && npm run dev || npm install && npm run dev
```

and for the docker-compose.yml, I just updated my volumes to

```
volumes:
      - ./../../.:/app
```

Could someone help me explain it? I thought dockerfile runs the npm install above but why it should be CMD [ -d "node_modules" ] && npm run dev || npm install && npm run dev before it works? Thank you

Comment: You should delete both `volumes:` blocks.  They overwrite everything in your image, which can result in inconsistent behavior.  The net effect is to use Node in a container against whatever code happens to be on the host system, which on the one hand loses the reproducibility you'll get with a Docker image and on the other hand is strictly harder than just running Node on the host without Docker.